# TypeScript: access class in global module/namespace

Tags: typescript

I've got the following situation:

```
module MyModule {
    export class Image {
        ...
    }

    var image = Image(); // returns an instance of MyModule.Image
}
```

However, I want to create an instance of HTMLImageElement, not MyModule.Image. How do I specify that I want to instantiate a class which resides in the global module/namespace?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways, but i would recommend using `document.createElement` in whatever way. For example:

```
var image = <HTMLImageElement>document.createElement('img');
```

You could create convenience functions or classes that wrap this for you.

One of the other ways would be for example to create a reference to the original Image class before your class definition:

```
var ImageElement = Image;

...

export class Image {
    ...
}

var image = new ImageElement()
```

however it won't be recognized as `HTMLImageElement` instance, ie no appropriate code completion.

**edit**: here's my *non-working* attempt to augment the `Window` interface as mentioned in the comments:

```
interface Window {
    Image: new(width?: number, height?: number) => HTMLImageElement;
}
```

It compiles correctly (ie without errors), but in Visual Studio it's flagged as an error, saying `Duplicate Identifier 'Image'`, and attempts to create an instance via `new window.Image()` are flagged saying `new expressions only valid on constructors`. Interestingly it works fine on other interfaces, and as already mentioned, it compiles correctly.

Comment: Thank you! While this helps in my particular case, it would be useful if there was an operator to address the global namespace, wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes it would. Being able to access `window.Image` would also do it, however `Image` is not defined on the `Window` interface, and i also wasn't able to define it there myself, not sure if that's possible at all.